# Pass Form Input Values (in real time) to another form on same page (hidden)

Tags: javascript, php, forms, pass-data

I have two forms on the same page with a link via javascript that switches back and forth between the two.

The page loads with form1 (for interested members to sign up) but at the bottom it says, "Are you a business? Click here", which then hides the member form and loads form2 (the business form).

Form1 has email, first name, last name and zip code.

Form2 has a dropdown for type of business, email, first name, last name, email, zip code and phone number.

I would like to pass the users input on form1 to form2 at the same time just in case they want to switch to the business form and not have to type in all the details from form1 again on form2.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you even tried?

Comment: Of course this is possible. Case closed.

Comment: Those are not answers to my question.

Comment: You asked "Is this possible?" and the second comment is *exactly* the answer to your question.

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily using jquery and either

```
.keyup();
.change();
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9cudt3k/)

Comment: What happens if one of the events isn't fired?

Comment: Thank you craig. I learned something new today and did not have to spend hours searching for an answer.

Comment: Well, you can use any event.  These are two events that fire in relation to text being input.  You could also use an event on a button: https://jsfiddle.net/m9cudt3k/1/